# Documentation with Workbench: Paclet vs Package

Tags: documentation, workbench

I am writing documentation for my package in Workbench v2.0 with Mathematica v9.0.1.  But for some reason, all of the help pages (and the index) of the package say that the various functions and symbols are "PACLET SYMBOL" [see screenshots].  But I want to it say "PACKAGE SYMBOL".  What option do I need to adjust to make the appropriate change?

---

**Image 1: Index**

[image]

---

**Image 2: Symbol page**

[image]

Comment: I don't get the extra "PACLET". I am using 10.0.1 with Workbench 3.0 release 78.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Workbench 3.0? I recently downloded from my Academic account and found only a 2.0 build 126 quite old...

Comment: @unlikely You can have a look [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/333053) for some details. Workbench 2 did not work with 10 on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Text from question is composed of two parts.

- First is controlled by "Paclet Name" cell in "Categorization" section of source notebook.
- Ending is added automatically based on "Entity Type" cell from "Categorization" section, but what precisely is added depends on your version of Workbench.

## Workbench 2.0.138

In Workbench 2.0.138 i.e. newest available from http://workbench.wolfram.com/update (it's an Eclipse Update Site so you won't get anything by clicking on the link).

If you have

Entity Type:

> Symbol

Paclet Name:

> MyPackageNameInCamelCase AnotherWord

You'll get in the search index:

> My Package Name In Camel Case Another Word Symbol

and on symbol page:

> MY PACKAGE NAME IN CAMEL CASE ANOTHER WORD SYMBOL

Default value of "Paclet Name" cell depends on how you create your source notebook.

- If using `AddPage` button in `Documentation` tab from paclet editor, then default value will be value of `Name` from `PacletInfo.m` file,
- If using `Create Symbol Pages` button, then default value will have `" Package"` appended to package name.

## Workbench 2.0.126

In Workbench 2.0.126 (newest available for some people from Wolfram User Portal) with `Entity Type`: `Symbol` you'll get "Paclet Symbol" ending.

You can update workbench to 138 build.

- If you're using Workbench as Eclipse plugin, by adding http://workbench.wolfram.com/update to [Available Software Sites](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-128.htm) and using ordinary [`Help` > `Check for updates`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-128.htm)
- For standalone workbench look at [Updating the Wolfram Workbench](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/updating.html) documentation (I don't have stand alone version so I can't give more details).

Comment: After making the change I get in my version (Workbench 2.0, Mathematica 9.0.1) "My Package Name In Camel Case Another Word Symbol Paclet Symbol".  "Paclet" is still there... any ideas?

Comment: @QuantumDot Sorry, I can't reproduce behavior that you're describing. I'm using Workbench 2.0.138 as plugin to Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1). I tried with MMA 8.0.0, 9.0.1 and 10.0.0 and I always get what's in my answer. Is it happening in a project into which you copied pre-existing package or made some renaming? Maybe you could try creating a fresh test project with a test symbol and test documentation page and check whether this problem is still there. Than we'll at least know if problem it's related to one project or to whole workbench.

Comment: @QuantumDot It seems this behavior was changed somewhere between 126 and 138 Workbench builds. Please read edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading, it works exactly as expected.  The documentation build is much more verbose, and has revealed some mysterious errors on every page that is being built (something about `{paclet:name/guide/name}` not being a replacement rule)...